# iText ignores SVG attribute overflow="visible"

Tags: itext7

I work with itext7-dotnet 8.0.2 and I want to add SVGs to my PDF.
My program gets the SVG from a service and I noticed that some symbols were missing in the PDF that were displayed normally when I opened the SVG in another application like Chrome.

After trying around I found out that the missing symbols are all  elements referenced by  elements and they have the attribute overflow="visible" while not defining any viewBox. The inner lying  element is outside of the normally visible area.

My workaround for this is to adjust the SVG that I receive by moving the ids from the  elements directly to the  elements. This works fine for me.

Here is a small example SVG with two  elements. One  element references the , the other one references the . Two number "3"s should be visible, but the iText PDF doesn't show the first "3" properly. I get the same result in other Applications when I remove the overflow="visible" attribute.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="501pt" height="313pt" viewBox="0 0 501 313" version="1.1">
    <defs>
        <g>
            <symbol overflow="visible" id="glyph0-0">
                <path id="glyph0-1" style="stroke:none;" d="M 0.707031 -3.175781 L 2.183594 -3.371094 C 2.351563 -2.53125 2.640625 -1.929688 3.046875 -1.5625 C 3.453125 -1.191406 3.949219 -1.007813 4.535156 -1.007813 C 5.230469 -1.007813 5.816406 -1.246094 6.292969 -1.730469 C 6.769531 -2.207031 7.007813 -2.804688 7.011719 -3.519531 C 7.007813 -4.195313 6.785156 -4.753906 6.347656 -5.195313 C 5.902344 -5.632813 5.339844 -5.851563 4.660156 -5.855469 C 4.378906 -5.851563 4.03125 -5.796875 3.617188 -5.691406 L 3.78125 -6.988281 C 3.875 -6.976563 3.957031 -6.972656 4.019531 -6.972656 C 4.644531 -6.972656 5.207031 -7.136719 5.714844 -7.464844 C 6.214844 -7.792969 6.46875 -8.296875 6.472656 -8.980469 C 6.46875 -9.519531 6.285156 -9.96875 5.921875 -10.324219 C 5.550781 -10.679688 5.078125 -10.855469 4.503906 -10.859375 C 3.925781 -10.855469 3.445313 -10.675781 3.066406 -10.316406 C 2.679688 -9.953125 2.433594 -9.414063 2.328125 -8.695313 L 0.851563 -8.957031 C 1.03125 -9.945313 1.441406 -10.710938 2.082031 -11.257813 C 2.71875 -11.796875 3.515625 -12.070313 4.46875 -12.074219 C 5.121094 -12.070313 5.726563 -11.929688 6.28125 -11.652344 C 6.835938 -11.367188 7.257813 -10.984375 7.550781 -10.5 C 7.839844 -10.011719 7.984375 -9.492188 7.988281 -8.949219 C 7.984375 -8.425781 7.847656 -7.953125 7.570313 -7.53125 C 7.289063 -7.101563 6.875 -6.761719 6.332031 -6.511719 C 7.039063 -6.34375 7.589844 -6.003906 7.988281 -5.488281 C 8.378906 -4.96875 8.578125 -4.324219 8.582031 -3.550781 C 8.578125 -2.5 8.195313 -1.609375 7.433594 -0.878906 C 6.664063 -0.152344 5.695313 0.210938 4.527344 0.214844 C 3.46875 0.210938 2.59375 -0.101563 1.898438 -0.726563 C 1.199219 -1.355469 0.800781 -2.171875 0.707031 -3.175781 Z M 0.707031 -3.175781 "/>
            </symbol>
        </g>
    </defs>
    <g style="fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;">
      <use xlink:href="#glyph0-0" x="10" y="20"/>
      <use xlink:href="#glyph0-1" x="30" y="20"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

The SVG code is originally created by Cairo afaik.

[Exptected result from my example SVG as displayed by Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTCbt.png)

[How it looks like in the PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8nw4.png)